# What is the most efficient way to read from the end of a file in c++? (Parsing last 128 bits in a file)

Tags: c++, file-io, bit, id3

I can think of a few quick ways of reading the last 128 bits, but which way is the easiest and most efficient?

Comment: Move the filepointer to the `EOF-16` and read til `EOF`.

Comment: I didn't write anything yet, but what I was going to do was read the file size, then seek to file size - 128. Though it doesn't seem like the most elegant solution.

Comment: @juergen d Haha guess it is an alright solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jump to the end and read:

```
char buf[16];

std::ifstream infile("thefile.bin", std::ios::binary);
infile.seekg(16, std::ios::end);

if (!infile || !infile.read(buf, 16))
{
    // error! Maybe die.
}

// process buf
```

Comment: @user979663: because 128 bits are 16 bytes on most architectures.